# Xamarin: orientation about card emulation mode and PC/SC APDU command

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, nfc, apdu

I'm learning Xamarin. I'm developing a demo with NFC. My goal is that the user, after pressing a button, can send an alphanumeric code via NFC to a reader. After pressing the button and putting the mobile phone on the reader, the reader must read the message sent by NFC and provide the information to another application.

I have noticed that Android provides functionality for card emulation mode but there is no such functionality for IOS. Also, I have seen about the PC/SC (Personal Computer/Smart Card) interface.

I would like to know if through an PC/SC APDU command a cell phone can write a value via NFC to a NFC reader that supports card emulation. Also, I would like to know if the PC/SC APDU command are standard or specific to each NFC reader.

Any information you can give me will be welcome.
Thank you